# javascript lightbox2 - how to add class to the opened img?

Tags: javascript, image, lightbox

I am having trouble with the lightbox2 plugin.
I have an image who has class on it, and I want that the class will also be added when the image opened in lightbox.

is it possible?

```
<a href="fileUpload/uploads/<?php echo $picture['gallery_src']; ?>" data-lightbox=<?php echo '"image-'.$picture['gallery_id'].'"' ?>>
        <img src=<?php echo '"fileUpload/uploads/'.$picture['gallery_src'].'"';?> id="filter-target" style="width:600px;">
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but where's your attempt?

Comment: kinda new here.. added it now :)

Comment: That's alright, welcome to SO. Do you want the class added to the full image or the thumbnail? If the full image, why not use the `lb-image` class which is automatically added

Comment: yes, I want to add it to the full image, but I want to add to each photo its own class (its a user select filters so there are many classes) and not one class for all.
is that posible? and also if there is maybe option to add one more attribute?

Comment: sorry for the delay. Can you give me an example of the result you'd like to achieve? I'm not sure what type of attribute you'd like adding.

Comment: thats ok :) I would like that the large photo will be something like this <img src="jordan.jpg" class="filter-blur" data-pb-blur-amount="5">

Comment: Ahh, you want multiple classes to be applied to the image being shown? One problem, your current php/html will result in multiple IDs `id="filter-target"`

Comment: yes didn't notice that..thanks! removed the multiple IDs its ok now.
back to the classes, is it possible to give it multiple classes and attributes?

Comment: See my answer. Note if you want different classes/attributes adding depending on the image selected, I'll need to know how to tell what values to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version of your PHP. Remember to remove your duplicate IDs

```
echo '<a href="fileUpload/uploads/'.$picture['gallery_src'].'" data-lightbox="image-'.$picture['gallery_id'].'">';
echo '<img src="fileUpload/uploads/'.$picture['gallery_src'].'" id="filter-target" style="width:600px;">';
echo '</a>';
```

You can add classes and data attributes to the image being viewed by running the following code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(e) {

  $('#lightbox .lb-image')
    .addClass('filter-blur')
    .data('pb-blur-amount', 5);
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/uSZpd/)

Comment: sry for the delay I fell asleep.. I tried to put the jquery and change the selector but it wont work.
also the class and data should change by the `$picture['gallery_id']` from the php, how can I make it?

Comment: You need to be clearer. `$picture['gallery_id']` has one value so I'm presuming it's the class name. Where do I get the data name and data value? Here's the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/uSZpd/1/)